# setting up my own RBL server for postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, rbl

I would like to setup my own rbl server for use with postfix.

1. Caching
2. The rbl server would reach out to a list of rbl servers.
3. I would also like to be able to collect stats to see if rbl servers are worth having on the list.  If it had too many false neg/pos I would remove it.  Think a rbl version of virustotal, but locally.

I found rbldnsd, but it hasn't been maintained since 2015, and it doesn't even respond on port 53 (also tried 55,1025,9999 for fun) which it binds to but does nothing with it.  Also no helpful docs.

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 rbldns rbldns ? 110 Dec 29 22:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 rbldns rbldns ?   8 Dec 29 18:29 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rbldns rbldns ?   0 Dec 29 18:43 127.0.0.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rbldns rbldns ?  31 Dec 29 19:01 forward
-rwxrwxrwx 1 rbldns rbldns ?   0 Dec 29 19:52 rbl.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rbldns rbldns ?  73 Dec 29 22:00 spammerlist
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   ?   0 Dec 29 18:29 spammerlist~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rbldns rbldns ?   0 Dec 29 18:29 whitelist
```

ls -alZ /var/lib/rbldns/

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 rbldns rbldns ?   8 Dec 29 18:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   ? 560 Dec 29 18:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 rbldns rbldns ? 110 Dec 29 22:00 dsbl
```

./rbldnsd -l rbl.log -f -r/var/lib/rbldns/dsbl/ -b 127.0.0.1 test:ip4set:spammerlist,whitelist bl.spamcom.net:generic:forward

I also tried "127.0.0.1:ip4set:spammerlist,whitelist", and dozens of other things.

netstat -an  |grep 53

shows them just fine, but I can even connect with netcat -u.  It does accept text but does nothing with it.

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find www.whatever.com: REFUSED
```

Comment: rbldnsd is maintained and works well.  I even use it as my authoritative public DNS server for all my domains.  It is listening on port 53.

Comment: @Aaron Please explain it to me.  Especially how to reference multiple external sources.  I did extensive testing to verify it wasn't the firewall.  All I ever get is connection REFUSED.  nslookup blah 127.0.0.1 refused.

Comment: even after chmod 777 rbl.log and changing ownership to rbldns:rbldns It still says it can't write to the log file?!!?!? What?

Comment: Are you using chroot in the config options?  What does your startup look like?  Do you have selinux enabled; and if so, what are the fcontexts of your rbldnsd files?  `ls -alZ`

Comment: @Aaron  I had added the request info, and a bit more.

Comment: You specified `/var/lib/rbldns/dsbl/` as the location to chroot into.  That means it would try to log to `/var/lib/rbldns/dsbl/var/lib/rbldns/dsbl/rbl.log` which is probably not what you want.  Just change the `-l` entry to `-l rbl.log`  Everything can be relative under your chroot definition.

Comment: Ok, logging stopped whinning, but I still have the same error.  See end of above posting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50966/discussion-between-cybernard-and-aaron).